# Why is the dropdown pushing down the lower div

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml

I have this [page](http://dev.posnation.com/po_systems/review.php?business_id=60&system_id=9B1DEF&quantity=1) and if you scroll to the middle you will see a `Select Shipping Method` dropdown and if you click on it. It will push the `Review Terms & Conditions` link down...here is my code

**HTML**

```
<div class="shipping-box lf">
<div class="ship-box1 lf">
    <div class="sel-ship lf">
        <div class="ss lf">
            <span class="lf">Select Shipping Method</span>
            <a class="ship-btn" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown lf" style="display:none;">
            <ul>
                <li class="ss-1 lf">1 Location</li>
                <li class="ss-2 lf">2 Location</li>
            </ul>       
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="terms lf">Review Terms & Conditions</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.shipping-box {
    height: 65px;
    padding-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
}

.lf {
    float: left;
}

.ship-box1 {
    width: 220px;
}

.sel-ship {
    width: 220px;
}

.terms {
    color: #009900;
    font-family: "helvetica neue";
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 200px;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.ship-box1, .ship-btn').click(function () {
    $(this).parents('.sel-ship').find('.dropdown').slideToggle();
    $(this).parents('.ss').toggleClass('ship-btn:hover');
    return false;
});
```

Any ideas on how to make sure the terms link stays in place

Comment: If you could create a http://jsfiddle.net/ it would help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This will fix it for you:

```
.sel-ship { position: relative; }
.dropdown { position: absolute; top: 25px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this:

```
.sel-ship{
    position:absolute;
}
.terms{
    margin-top:30px;
}
```

Comment: this did the trick but can you explain why this works....I assumed position absolute positioned an element on the page from the top and left...Im not following on how this fixes it

Comment: @Tamer: position absolute positions an element absolute to the next **positioned** element (a parent element with `position` set). In your case `.shipping-box`

Comment: so basically it will position the absolute element based on the nearest (travesing up) positioned element (absolute, or relative)

Answer (score 1):

Set for `.sel-ship` class `position:absolute;`, for `.terms` class set `margin-top:35px;`

Comment: this did the trick but can you explain why this works....I assumed position absolute positioned an element on the page from the top and left...Im not following on how this fixes it

Comment: If you position your element as `position:absolute` the element will be positioned relative to its first positioned ancestor element. If you set `top` or `left` properties - it will move your element to the top left corner of the window or to closest element with `position:relative;`.

Comment: so basically it will position the absolute element based on the nearest (travesing up) positioned element (absolute, or relative)